# Drum machine sequencing involving jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have the following code:

```
  var blinker = function(element){
  if(stopped){
    return;
  } else {
  var sampleMapping = {'0': 'bass.wav',
                 '1': 'clap(2).wav',
                 '2': 'hihat(4).wav',
                 '3': 'tom(9).wav',
                 '4': 'hihat.wav',
                 '5': 'ArpEC1.wav'}

  if (element.attr('value') === 'hit'){
    var sample = element.attr('id');
    instrument(sample);
  }
    element.fadeOut(200);
    element.fadeIn(200);
    }
  }

  var sequencerRun = function(){    
  var currentTime = 0;
  var starting = 200;
  var startTime = 0;
    for(var k = 0; k < 16; k++){
      $(".instrument td .beat" + k).each(function(){
        setTimeout(blinker, currentTime,$(this));
      })
      currentTime += starting;
    }
  }

  var timerId, setInt;

  var runSeq = function(){
    setInt = setInterval(sequencerRun,3200);
  }

  $('.play').click(function(){
    stopped = false
    sequencerRun();
    runSeq();
  })

  $('.stop').click(function(){
    clearInterval(setInt);
    stopped = true;
  })
```

I have writting code to carry out a sequencer run in my drum machine. A deployed version of my app can be seen [here](https://moneymakerdrums.herokuapp.com/)

So what I have done is created a matrix using a `table` HTML structure. When play is clicked sequencerRun is invoked and runs once. After this first run setInterval takes care invoking all sequencerRun until a user clicks stop. There is a flag within these click event listeners which I will come back to.

The heart of this sequencing is with `sequencerRun`. For each column in my matrix, which corresponds to a beat, I am scheduling a check on that column to see if any element has been selected for future play. `sequencerRun` only takes care of scheduling. More explicitly:

```
setTimeout(blinker,0, $(this)) is the same as check the first column right away
setTimeout(blinker,0, $(this)) is the same as check the second column at time 200
setTimeout(blinker,0, $(this)) is the same as check the third column at time 400
....
setTimeout(blinker,0, $(this)) is the same as check the sixteenth column at time 3200
```

Now what `blinker` does is checks to see if stopped, the original flag I created is true or false. It becomes true when clicking stop which then means that the column check is not carried out and nothing is play. If false then the normal process of the drum machine is carried out.

Now here's the problem. If you go to the deployed version of the app this flagging introduces a nasty bug. That bug is if you press play the sequencer starts, but if click play again another run is started which is not how a drum machine is supposed to work. Essentialy what I would like to see is if I press play no other sequencerRun should kick off if I press play again. Also if you click play, stop, play I get the same side effect. I think my main problems are the fact that `sequencerRun` schedules future beats right away and my flagging.  Any one have any idea on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make use of your `stopped` variable within the `.play` click handler:

```
$('.play').click(function(){
    if (stopped) {
        stopped = false
        sequencerRun();
        runSeq();
    }
});
```

If the `stopped` flag is false, clicking play again will do nothing.  To stop the rest of the queued sequence when you click stop, you'll need to clear the timeouts that have been set.  First of all, make sure you keep a handle to each of them:

```
var sequenceTimeouts = [];
var sequencerRun = function(){    
    var currentTime = 0;
    var starting = 200;
    var startTime = 0;
    //reset array
    sequenceTimeouts = [];
    for(var k = 0; k < 16; k++){
        $(".instrument td .beat" + k).each(function(){
            //push each timeout into the array
            sequenceTimeouts.push(setTimeout(blinker, currentTime,$(this)));
        })
        currentTime += starting;
    }
 }
```

Then within your stop click handler, clear each of those:

```
$.each(sequenceTimeouts, function(i, timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
});
```

Comment: Awesome. That works for clicking play multiple times. The bigger problem is when click play, stop, play. When you click play a third time the first run is still running since it was scheduled for a check and the flag has changed, so you end up getting 2 runs. How can I terminate the first sequencerRun when stop is clicked?

Comment: @theamateurdataanalyst Edited my answer, assuming I've understood you correctly :)

Comment: You my friend are a genius.